# Getting a file name into a variable using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch file which needs to perform operations on a specific file each day.  So far, the file names have followed the pattern `EX_2017-08-30.DAT` which means I could use the following to get the exact filename for the day:

```
set today=%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%
set filename=EZ_%today%.DAT
```

Now I'm being told the filenames will change to include a timestamp, such as `EX_2017-08-30-231859.DAT`.  However, the exact time won't be known beforehand (it gets set when a certain process completes).

I can't use a wildcard throughout the batch file because the filename is being written to an external file for another application to use, so I have to know the exact filename.  Is there anyway that I can do a search with a wildcard and store the resulting complete filename into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can list the files in the directory your EX_* file is in, you can do:

```
for %%i in (EX_%today%-*.DAT) do (
    set filename=%%i
)
```

The first line lists all files in the directory matching the date and the extension, and then it sets the last file to the `filename` variable. Be careful as this does not throw any warnings should there be more than one file matching the expression.

If you cannot list the directory, your only chance is bruteforce. There are only 24*60*60 possibilities of the filename, and if you go backwards in time, you should reach the desired file in just a couple of thousands of iterations, providing the task is usually completed close to midnight.

Comment: I believe I do have access to list the files, so this seems like it would do the trick.  Before I accept this answer, I would suggest that you change `echo %%i` to `set filename=%%i` so it more directly answers my question (setting the filename to a variable, rather than just listing filenames).

Comment: @techturtle: Cool, I have done just that. I have also pointed out potential problems with this approach.